# Remove Neo4J node labels using a collection?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, label

Is it possible to remove labels from a node using a collection? Something like the following, which doesn't work, I assume because it is trying to remove the "remove_labels" label instead of using that as a collection of labels to remove.

Assume that all nodes with "label_3" also have labels "label_1" and "label_2".

```
WITH ["label_1", "label_2"] as keep_labels
MATCH (n:label_3 {id: 5})
WITH filter(label IN labels(n) WHERE label NOT(IN keep_labels)) AS remove_labels
MERGE (n:label_3 {id: 5})
REMOVE n:remove_labels
RETURN n
```

--- EDIT ---
Fixed invalid 'cg' reference which was a copy-paste error. Also added an explicit keep_labels collection, though in my query that will be a parameter.

Comment: What is `cg`? This query should throw an error saying `cg` is not defined. Same for `keep_labels`.

Comment: Sorry, one was a copy-paste error and another was just an implied parameter. I've edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifying labels dynamically in Cypher is not currently supported. You'd have to handle this in client code and build the Cypher query string, explicitly specifying the label.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Any idea if it is on a roadmap?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. There is a feature request for this behavior on Github if you'd like to track there: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/1809